# Is there a way to completely pause the game?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

Whenever I open the map or the menu, the world around me seems to continue moving. Is there a way to completely pause the game? Playing on the PS4, it does not seem like the PS button menu pauses the game either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going into a full screen option menu works for pausing. Go into the equipment menu or the passive skill tree menu and the game will pause.